# Greasemonkey - integrating scroll and mouse click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have a bunch of links on a page where I am playing a game.

The requirement is to scroll to the link and click on it. I have managed to click on it.

```
function clickLinkWithText () {
    var links = $('a[href*="xyz.com"]');
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length);   
    var targetLink = links.get(randomNum);
    triggerMouseEvent (targetLink, "click"); 
}
```

But first, how do I scroll to the element and then click on it. What should I change here?

```
function scrollToElement() {    
   window.setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);", 
   1000);
};

window.addEventListener('mouseover',function() {
    scrollToElement()
},true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most browsers you can scroll to an element by calling `scrollIntoView()` on it. Then, you can set a small timeout (so that the browser has time to scroll to the element), after which you can click on the element. For example, the following userscript will scroll to your username and click it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         scroll-click
// @namespace    CertainPerformance
// @version      1
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341101/greasemonkey-integrating-scroll-and-mouse-click-action
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const a = document.querySelector('a[href="/users/1089173/curiousdev"]');

function scrollToElement() {
  a.scrollIntoView();
  setTimeout(() => {
    a.click();
  }, 1000);
};

window.addEventListener('mouseover', scrollToElement);
```

Note that there's no need for jQuery, and that you can pass the function name *directly* to `addEventListener` rather than wrapping it in another anonymous function.

Also, try to avoid ever passing strings to `setTimeout` - that's basically the same as `eval`. Better to pass an actual function.

Comment: This looks cool. So after var targetLink = links.get(randomNum); Do I call scrollToElement() and pass targetLink as the parameter? When do I call triggerMouseEvent (targetLink, "click"); then ? Sorry, I tried but I am missing something.

Comment: You can copy-paste the entire userscript in the answer and it should work for you. As you can see, the current `scrollToElement` doesn't accept a parameter, but you can easily tweak it to use `a` as a parameter rather than using the outer scoped variable, and then you can pass it whichever `a` you want, to scroll to it and click it.

Comment: Can you also help me with Q. 52585410